# Mod Rewrite swaping address

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have right url: `example.com/contact.php` and I want to redirect this to fake url `example.com/contact/`.

If I make

```
RewriteRule ^contact\.php$ /contact [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^contact$ /contact\.php [NC,L]
```

then this creates infinity loop.

Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `THE_REQUEST` variable for this. `THE_REQUEST` variable represents original request received by Apache from your browser and it doesn't get overwritten after execution of some rewrite rules. Example value of this variable is `GET /index.php?id=123 HTTP/1.1`

Put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# external redirect from /contact.php to /contact
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(contact)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L,NE]

# To internally forward from /contact to /contact.php
RewriteRule ^(contact)/?$ $1.php [L,NC]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have a few questions. Is it required `\s` before `/+(contact)\.php[\s?]` and second question: how works `^ %1 `?

Also I don't know why in `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php` can I use `$1` if i didn't name this before ..

Comment: `\s` is to match space after `GET` in `THE_REQUEST` text. And since all the matching is done in `RewriteCond` therefore `RewriteRule ^ %1` just redirects to captured group #1 from `RewriteCond`. More details here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html

Comment: OK i know how `^ %1`  works. Simply if it contains `contact.php` the request will be send. You made forward also for /contact/ but for me it doesn't work. Do you have any ideas why?

Comment: For you also forward worked but you didn't use `%{THE_REQUEST}` and that caused redirect loop.

Comment: You misread me. `RewriteRule ^(contact)/?$ $1.php [L,NC]` should works booth `/contact` and `/contact/` but works only first one.

Comment: Yes it should work for both `/contact` and `/contact/`. Is `/contact/` a directory?

Comment: All this is working on my server so rules are 100% working. Difficult to guess for me what's wrong on your web server.

Comment: It is weird because on my virtual apache it doesn't work either

Comment: Yes definitely weird since it works for me on 3 different Apache version on OSX and Linux.

Comment: ahh it isn't  mod rewrite fault. I have some bug in my phpfile... thank for help! :)